# ionic3 Refresh the page and report the following error

Tags: ionic3

[image]

The following error occurs when the page is modified and refreshed.

Comment: GET http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js 0 ()
(index):52 GET http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js 0 ()
(index):55 GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.js 0 ()
(index):39 GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.css 0 ()
(index):58 GET http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 0 ()
(index):28 GET http://localhost:8100/cordova.js 0 ()
ion-dev.js?v=3.1.0:101 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:53703/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Your ionic serve command is stopped. Restart/Reconnect ionic serve command to run your project. Otherwise, if you have created a new page and it contains the module, you need to run the command again.